# How to process http-Calls in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: arrays, rest, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm currently trying to set up the Rest-API for my Ionic2 Application. As backend I'm using Crud-API which is working fine already. But I'm running into problems when calling the API from the APP.

I'm using the following class as a service to make the http call:

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class NoteService {
static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
}

constructor(private http:Http) {

}

searchNotes() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/plotnote/api_crud.php/note/1';
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
}
}
```

Then I use the searchNotes-Method of this service to get the results and write them in the array notes:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NoteService} from '../services/NoteService';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [NoteService]
})

export class HomePage {

notes: Array<any>;

constructor(private navController: NavController, private noteService:                     NoteService) {
    this.listNotes();
    console.log("notes: " + this.notes);
}

listNotes() {
  this.noteService.searchNotes().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.notes = data.results;
      console.log('Data: ');
      console.log(data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => console.log('Note Search Complete')
  );
}

}
```

Finally to display the notes I do the following:

```
<ion-content class="home" padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let note of notes">
            <ion-card-content>
                {{note.text}}
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Sadly this doesn't work at all :(.
I tried to find the problem through the js-console and it looks like I'm getting the right data from the api, but there seems to be a problem with putting the data into the notes-Array.
Here is a screenshot of the console-output:
[js-console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn1a1.png)

I hope you guys can help me to find the problem and get this thing working :)

Comment: Seems like the service returns an object and not an array. That's why the ngFor wouldn't work.

Comment: @C_Ogoo Oh thx :). How could i return the data as an array then?